# MongoDB GridFS.findOne possible delay before result is valid?

Tags: mongodb, timing, gridfs

In my application I'm calling

```
GridFSDBFile f = gfs.findOne (new ObjectId(gridId))
```

This usually returns a valid file that was previously created by a call to

```
GridFSInputFile gridFile = gfs.createFile(someFile.getBytes())
gridFile.save()
```

But sometimes it returns null. So I put it in a while loop

```
while (!f)
{
   f = gfs.findOne(new ObjectId(gridId))
   Thread.sleep(200)
}
```

This returns a valid file after the second call after about 400 ms have elapsed. Am I doing something wrong or is there a possible delay after a file is created to the time you can access it?

Comment: Are you reading off of a slave? If so, there might be a delay between the write to the master and the replicate to the slave.

Comment: Same question as http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/9b90135104b1bdeb

Comment: DB db = ...getDB()
db.requestStart();
    //do the savingDBObject err = db.getLastError();
   db.requestDone();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identical with http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/9b90135104b1bdeb?pli=1 and already answered there by the 10gen people - not sure why this question must be posted on a different platform where the mongo users list the likely the best platform for getting help from the official maintainers.

Comment: thanks that pretty much answers it. I found a detailed answer here http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/mongodb-single-server-data-durability-guide/#overview